# Integral of absolute value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have the following integral which I want to make sure to solve correctly and transparently:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\|e^{ax}\|dx
\end{equation}
If I take cases I obtain:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\|e^{ax}\|dx=\|\frac{1}{a}e^{ax}\|$ but I don't know how to play with the absolute value inside the integral to obtain a more transparent solution.

i was thinking to move the abolute value like this $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\|e^{ax}\|dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\|ax\|}dx$ and go from there but I don't think this is correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: $e^{ax}$ is negative if.. when is it negative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that you are trying to integrate $e^{ax}>0$ for all x in its domain so it is equal to its absolute value for all x in domain.

Comment: Right, that's a very good point which I missed.I got confused by the fact that the integral can take negative values. But of course I shouldn't care  about that. Thanks.